# My login form does not work

Tags: login, forms

I have the following code that generates a login form for every page in my blog.

```
<form action="<?php echo wp_login_url(); ?>" method="post">
username: <br />
<input name="log" id="login_username" type="text" />
<br />
password: <br />
<input name="pwd" id="login_password" type="password" />
<br />
<br />
<input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" value="forever" />
remember me
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="/" />
<input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
</form>
```

But it doesn't work. It just lands the user in login page.
I'm wondering if I have left out a part of the form!

**SOLVED**: I should've just put a hidden input in the form with name of `login` and some value like `true`.

Comment: Please post your solution as a separate answer and mark it as "the" answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should've just put a hidden input in the form with name of `login` and some value like `true`.

Answer (score 5):

If you read the documentation on [`wp_login_url`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url), you can specify a redirect URL without having to use that hidden input field. Alternatively, you could just use the [`wp_login_form`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) function to do exactly what you want:

`<?php wp_login_form(); ?>` Just toss that in there in place of your form, and read the documentation on that function to learn how to customize it.

Comment: +1 for `wp_login_form()`. See also: [`wp_loginout()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout).

Comment: I knew about the `wp_login_form()` but I needed that code to work. It appears even the `wp_login_form()` doesn't work either. It seems the problem is elsewhere.